# Populate data from MySQL on Laravel Page

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a bootstrap drop down on a Laravel page(Sign Up page) and would like to populate it using data from my MySQL database. So in my routes, I have something like this:

```
Route::get('/signup', [
    'uses' => 'SigninSignupController@getSignup',
    'as' => 'signup'
]);
```

And in my SigninSignupController:

```
public function getSignup(){
    $users = DB::table('users')->get();
    return view('pages.signup', ['users' => $users]);
}
```

In my signup.blade.php:

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
   <option> {{ $user->orgid; }} </option>
@endforeach
```

But I get an error like this : http://pastebin.com/543VGaq9

In my SigninSignupController, I have these:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

What am I doing wrong? Can someone point it out?

Comment: `Namespace` needs to come before the `use` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `namespace` and `use` to:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use DB;
```

Also, you don't need to use `;` in Blade templates, so it should look like:

```
{{ $user->orgid }}
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm, just stuck with the traditional PHP way

Comment: could you help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39508556/issue-with-route-protection-in-laravel-5-3