# Issue with Route Protection in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-routing, laravel-5.3

I have made a login/signup page in Laravel and it works fine but I want to protect routes by allowing authenticated users alone to access the url.

This is my web.php :

```
Route::get('/', [
    'uses' => 'UserController@getLogin',
    'as' => 'login'
]);

Route::get('/signup', [
    'uses' => 'UserController@getSignup',
    'as' => 'signup'
]);

Route::get('/logout', [
        'uses' => 'UserController@getLogout',
        'as' => 'logout'
]);

Route::group(['prefix' => 'app'], function(){

    Route::post('/newuser', [
        'uses' => 'UserController@postSubmitSignup',
        'as' => 'submitsignup'
    ]);

    Route::post('/submitsignup', [
            'uses' => 'UserController@postSubmitLogin',
            'as' => 'submitlogin'
    ]);

    Route::get('/home', [
            'uses' => 'UserController@getDashboard',
            'as' => 'dashboard'
    ])->middleware('auth');

    // I also tried 'middleware' => 'auth', ends in same thing

});
```

In my UserController.php :

```
public function getSignup(){
    $organizations = Organizations::all()->where('deleted', '0')->all();
    return view('pages.signup', ['organizations' => $organizations]);
}

public function getLogin(){
    return view('pages.login');
}

public function getDashboard(){
    return view('pages.dashboard');
}

public function getLogout(){
    Auth::logout();
    return redirect()->route('login');
}

public function postSubmitSignup(Request $request){

    $newuser = new User();

    $newuser->firstname = $request['firstname'];
    $newuser->lastname = $request['lastname'];
    $newuser->username = $request['username'];
    $newuser->email = $request['email'];
    $newuser->password = bcrypt($request['password']);
    $newuser->passwordhint = $request['passwordhint'];
    $newuser->organization = $request['organization'];
    $newuser->location = $request['location'];
    $newuser->phone = $request['phone'];
    $newuser->signupnote = $request['remarks'];

    $newuser->save();

    return redirect()->route('login');
}

public function postSubmitLogin(Request $request){
    if(Auth::attempt(["username" => $request['username'], "password" => $request['password']])){
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }

    session()->flash('invalid', 'Bad Credentials');
    return redirect()->back()->withInput();

}
```

And when I try to login with valid credentials, I get the following error message and the url seems to be `http://website.com/login` but the login page is located at `http://website.com/`:

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
1/1 NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

    in RouteCollection.php line 161
    at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 780
    at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 610
    at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 596
    at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 267
    at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
```

When I try to access the dashboard url directly, I get the same error. How should I do it properly and would be great if someone can explain why this happens.

Comment: You just want to protect the routes or what?

Comment: If you want to protect some specific routes just group it in auth middle ware that's it.
`Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function(){ 
 //your routes
}`

Comment: So they don't need to be under web? I seen tutorial putting them under web and doing like what I did. Another thing is like, in 5.3 the routes are by default in web.

Comment: ya that was necessary in laravel 5 and previous versions. In 5+ versions it is not necessary to put every thing under web. In 5.3 there is a separate web.php and api.php .

Comment: Yes how do i protect my route in 5.3 then?

Comment: still there is auth middleware, so you can group your routes you wanna protect in a auth middleware

Comment: @lftikhar uddin Here is my complete application and its route : [code] (https://github.com/yeshwanthvshenoy/De-Bug/blob/master/routes/web.php) and in 5.3, seems all the routes under web.php are grouped under web middleware. Where should I put the routes if I need them under auth. Could you give me an example for this in 5.3.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group your routes like below

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function(){

  Route::get('/logout', [
        'uses' => 'UserController@getLogout',
        'as' => 'logout'
  ]);


// and your other routes which you wanna protect
}
```

Now the logout route and other routes which you will add in there will be only accessible to the authenticated users, in simple words user who is logged in.

Comment: @liftikhar uddin no still doesn't work. I get the same thing. Here is my entire project : [GitHub] (https://github.com/yeshwanthvshenoy/De-Bug). Could you please point out whats wrong? I am stuck in something very small.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/iftikharuddin/9ef222dafb2e47d8e715faefbf89c03c Try this and now everything which is in group middleware auth will be only accessible to logged in users

Comment: No this doesn't solve it. I get the same error as I mentioned above.

Comment: What error? I am protecting the routes, i am not talking about errors/

Comment: I am ending up with the same as like above mentioned in the question. It doesn't protect the routes